# How to compare two arrays of strings, find all matches, when there might be a sentence?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, string

This is a fun one - I am building a profanity checker!

For the purposes of this exercise, let's have an array of forbidden words, like so:

`const forbiddenWords = ['apples', 'oranges', 'blue carrots', 'mushy green peas'];`

Then I will have an input field for a user to input the something. It could be an infinite combo of words, but I would like to find ALL instances of the forbidden words and return them as an array. I've thought of this function, which gets me really close:

```
const forbiddenWords = ['apples', 'oranges', 'blue carrots', 'mushy green peas'];
const userInput = 'Broccoli is my favorite food. I hate oranges and blue carrots';

    const checkIfValidInput = () => {
        // Will return an array that looks like: ['Broccoli', 'is', 'my', 'favorite', ...]
        const splitWords = userInput.split(" ");
        const array = [];
        for (let i in forbiddenWords) {
            if (splitWords.indexOf(forbiddenWords[i]) !== -1) {
                array.push(forbiddenWords[i]);
            }
        }
        return array.sort((x, y) => x - y);
    };
```

Running the above will make the result of array be `['oranges', 'blue', 'carrots']`. How could I build out the function to check for `'blue carrots'` or `'mushy green peas'` all in one? I'd like the above function to return: `['oranges', 'blue carrots']`.
Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex for this situation. This will also give you ability to match with case insensitivity

```js
const checkIfValidInput = () => {
  const forbiddenWords = ['apples', 'oranges', 'blue carrots', 'mushy green peas'];
  const userInput = 'Broccoli is my favorite food. I hate oranges and blue carrots';
  
  const result = forbiddenWords.reduce((acc, words) => {
    const match = userInput.match(new RegExp(words, ['gi']))
    return match ? acc.concat(match) : acc
  }, [])
  result.sort()
  console.log(result)
}

checkIfValidInput()
```

Also, `array.sort((x, y) => x - y);` is not required as the values you have are string. You can rely on `array.sort()` or if you really want to do manual sort, try `string.localeCompare(string2)`

Answer (score 0):

You're probably best off creating a regular expression. This way, you can skip the next to split and ignore capitalization issues

You can do this like

```
var regexStr = "";
for (let i = 0; i < forbiddenWords.length; i++) {
  if (i != 0) regexStr += "|";
  regexStr+= "(" + forbiddenWords[i] + ")";
}

var regex = RegExp.compile(regexStr,"gim");

var matches = userInput.match(regex);
```

Comment: A shorter way for your regex: `new RegExp("(" + forbiddenWords.join("|") + ")", "gim")`

Comment: I thought that RegExp.compile has been deprecated? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/compile

Answer (score 0):

You can check the sentence with every single phrases whether it's a match or not and if it's then you can return the phrase and store in a variable.

Technically, using of filter() and includes() would resolve the task. Lemme know if it helps.

```
let matched = forbiddenWords.filter(phrase => { 
    if(userInput.includes(phrase)) return phrase;
});

return matched;
```